# how can i get values from HashMap<String, Object> inside Obect []?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

Here's my User Entity field

```
    @Schema
private Object[] alreadyShownUser;
```

how can i get values from HashMap<String, Object> inside Obect [] ?

```
        "alreadyShownUser": [
        {
            "shownUserId": "63d357149dac903ab670d577",
            "shownAt": "2023-01-30T07:19:52.295+00:00"
        },
        {
            "shownUserId": "63a4196c62533371159762fd",
            "shownAt": "2023-01-30T07:21:00.243+00:00"
        }
```

i need only "shownUserId"'s values

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, each element in your `Object[] alreadyShownUser` is a `HashMap<String, Object>`. If that's the case then you can just cast it:

```
for(Object o:alreadyShownUser) {
   HashMap<String, Object> theMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) o;
   System.out.println(theMap.get("shownUserId"));
}
```